# Cambiar el color por defecto de un dropdown en el componente calendar de PrimeNg

Tags: angular, calendar, primeng

estoy utilizando angular con el componente Calendar de PrimeNg aqui la documentacion https://www.primefaces.org/primeng/#/calendar. => ***Month Picker***

El componente calendar tiene dos parametros de entrada **monthNavigator** y **yearNavigator** lo que hacen es si pasas true al input te muestra un dropdown en la cabecera del calendar donde por defecto muestra un dropdown cuyo color del valor seleccionado es azul. Lo que pasa es que quiero cambiar ese color y no lo logro hacer ya que no puedo saber cual es el elemento seleccionado porque en el html todos los elementos del select se muestran con la misma clase lo cual no puedo aplicar selector al que esta seleccionado y cambiar el color. Tambien queria cambiar el color que se muestra cuando pasas el raton sobre los elementos del select ya que tambien por defecto es azul. Existe alguna forma de hacer esto.  Muchas gracias

```
<select class="ui-datepicker-year ng-tns-c3-14 ng-star-inserted">
<option class="ng-tns-c3-14 ng-star-inserted" value="2000">2000</option>
<option class="ng-tns-c3-14 ng-star-inserted" value="2001">2001</option>
<option class="ng-tns-c3-14 ng-star-inserted" value="2002">2002</option>
<option class="ng-tns-c3-14 ng-star-inserted" value="2003">2003</option>
...
</select>
```

Comment: Según la documentación hay dos propiedades llamadas inputStyle e inputStyleClass, has probado ya con estas ?

Comment: No lo he probado pero esas dos propriedades me permitirian cambiar el color por defecto del dropdwon: Abria que crear una clase y pasarla a estas propriedades para qe cambie el color del dropdownd. Perdon pero no lo veo claro.

Comment: Si, exacto, en inputStyle podrias pasar los estilos o si no crear una clase en tu css global y ponerla en inputStyleClass. Puede ser que eso defina el estilo del input del que hablas

Comment: Pero aun asi creo que no se va solucionar el problema porque yo no se cual es el elemento que esta seleccionado ya que el html no me lo indica no tiene ningua clase que me lo indique.